# Updating popcorn time app

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, desktop-apps

I have this app for watching movies, but it does not show up in Ubuntu Software Center, nor can I uninstall it or update it. I cannot tell what version I have, because I cannot find it among the installed packages.
I tried dpkg --get-selections | grep -i popcor
and nothing shows up. Any help, please?

The reason I am trying to update it or reinstall it is that I always get 'Error loading data' on the home screen of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [web site](http://itsfoss.com/netflix-piracy-popcorn-time/) tells you how to install the current version.

The commands you need are:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/popcorntime
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install popcorn-time

Comment: `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/popcorntime'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`